Is Python multiprocessing.Lock also thread safe?
I am wondering if Lock imported from multiprocessing module is also thread safe.

This question is similar to: Safe to call multiprocessing from a thread in Python?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes. But if all of the threads are running in the same process, it is less expensive to use a threading.Lock.
